# 100% CPU utilization on IIS during databinding

Tags: asp.net, iis, data-binding

We are about to launch a site which will have 12,000-15,000 active users (around 2000 concurrent). During performance tests, we had some CPU bottlenecks and at the end we have a very simple aspx page which we can reproduce this problem as follows.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" trace="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    Sub pp(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Page.IsPostBack Then Exit Sub
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        For I = 1 To 10
            For Each c As Control In Me.Form.Controls
                lst.Add(c.ID)
            Next
        Next
        'r1.DataSource = Lst
        'r1.DataBind()
    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><asp:Button ID="b1" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button10" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button11" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button12" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button13" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button14" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button15" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button16" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button17" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button18" Text="Button" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Repeater ID="r1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- It is a two core test machine.
- It is a WebForms application.
- Memory is not used at all (2GB of 32GB used.)
- Output Caching is disabled. (Yes opening is a fallback option.)
- And yes IIS wp is using 100% of CPU.
- It is not in debug mode.
- We are using ab (Apache bench) for load testing. (It was same with tinyget as well.)
- Unloaded page trace (`trace="true"`) completes in 0.3s including rendering.
- When ab requests hit to the server, page trace completes in 0.7s but actual page's return to browser takes 8s.
- No it is not network bandwidth (load runner and server on the same network and network utilization remains 1.4%.
- Requests are not waiting IIS request queue. (Checked with PerfMon.)
- DebugDiag full dumps does not spot any relevant problem.
- ab -n8000 -c500 urlofthepage.aspx
- With above load, cpu reaches 100% immediately and we can handle 154req/sec.

Requests per second:    154.13 [#/sec] (mean)

When we increase CPU cores, this number increases but it is still 100% utilized

If we comment out following databinding statements response totally different:

```
r1.DataSource = l
r1.DataBind()
```

Requests per second:    2510.95 [#/sec] (mean)

We are stuck. Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Could you elaborate on versions: iis .net etc. Why do you have the outer loop 1 to 10? Loop variable never used. Also how big is the list of control ids?

Comment: Do you have any think time in your bench definition between requests for the page in question?

Comment: We have tried IIS 7.5 and 8.
It is an .Net 2.0 application but we have tried this sample on 4.0 as well. 
No. We dont have think time. Because concurrent 500 will mean 3000 users with think times. 
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Examine your HTTP request logs.  If you have 500 users hitting the same page at the same time then you have automated agents hitting the page on a clock tick and not humans.  Consider multicast broadcasts to subscribers in such a case.